# Trying to get the list of all the attributes in a column in dynamodb in python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb

I have a sample table like below

[image]

My code to retrieve the `product_name` is as below

```
import boto3
import json
import decimal


dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            if o % 1 > 0:
                return float(o)
            else:
                return int(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

response = dynamodb.scan(
    TableName='inventory'
    )


for i in response['Items']: 
    json_str = json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder)
    resp_dict = json.loads(json_str)
    print (resp_dict.get('product_name'))
```

Now when I try to get the list of all `product_name`, I am getting the following

```
{'S': 'Butter'}
{'S': 'Wine'}
```

but all i need is to get

```
'Butter'
'Wine'
```

How can I get the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this by replacing this

```
print (resp_dict.get('product_name'))
```

with

```
print (resp_dict.get('product_name')['S'])
```

or

```
print (resp_dict.['product_name']['S'])
```